# How can i send proactive message from a Tabs App to a Channel in Microsoft Teams

Tags: blazor-webassembly, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm working on a Microsoft Teams tab app using Blazor and need to implement proactive messaging to channels without adding a bot to my solution. While exploring the Microsoft Graph API, I have a few concerns:

- Is Microsoft Graph API the recommended approach for sending proactive messages from a Blazor tab app without using a bot?
- My app is designed to be multi-tenant. Do other tenants need to perform any specific actions for this feature to work like assiging a role in entra ? I'm looking for solution that wont need clients to make additional configurations in their Azure AD.
- I consulted multiple documentaion , but having problem visualizing what should be done.  I am looking for a clear idea about this.